# Letting users remove webform submissions they've made earlier

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a website where people can sign up for events. The client now wants the users be able to delete their submission for the event, by entering their email address, displaying a list of events they're attending, and choose which event they want to remove themselves from.

Is there any module that adds this functionality, or is it something that can be done out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Implement sign ups as nodes instead of as webform submissions. Then you can grant the `delete own [node type] nodes` permission to allow users to cancel the sign up.

Comment: I'd like the users not to be able to access the administration, to sign up for events - can I somehow add the node creation form to a specific page?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the administration"? Drupal does not make a clear distinction between administration and non-administration. Thats for you to do by assigning different permissions to different roles.

Answer (score 0):

The webform_xyz tables let you easily find this information. You can show it in a form and let the user delete his subscription.

However this isn't really secure, since all you need to know is the email address of a person to delete (or just lookup) his subscriptions. This might be no problem for a small, closed user group in an intranet. For a public site you have to identify the users. The easiest way is that they have to become drupal users before they can register and then delete themselves again.